# Failed to get data from mongoDB, I get HTML template instead of data

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I want to retrieve data from **mongoDB**, a collection of **products**, But instead of an array or an object with data, I get an HTML template. What can this be related to?  The database is connected, I checked.
Screenshots below.

**model product**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  price: Number,
  quantity: Number,
});

const Product = mongoose.model("products", productSchema);

module.exports =  Product ;
```

**server**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const  Product  = require("./models/Products");

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
  Product.find((error, data) => {
    if (!error) {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  });
});
```

**axios from the client side**

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

**client**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await axios.get("/api/products");
      console.log('product >>>', data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

**mongoDB, collection product**

[image]

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured for your Vite system?  Otherwise, what server is the `axios.get('/api/products')` connecting to?

Comment: The server is running on port 8080 on my local network.
connected at `http://localhost:8080/api/products`

Comment: But how does your web app know that?  Your browser is making a request to `/api/products` ... where in your setup does your browser know that the request should be proxied to `http://localhost:8080` ?

Typically you would set up a PROXY configuration in your UI development system (create-react-app or vite or whatever you are using).  For Vite see: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy  For CRA see: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

Axios baseURL was not set.
You can create an axiosInstance with baseURL and use it to call the api.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
  headers: {
    Authorization: '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
axiosInstance.get('/api/products');
```

Comment: I did as you advised, specified the **baseURL** for axios, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. :(


**terminal** `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')`
**browser** `GET http://localhost:8080/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: It looks like the Product model was not imported correctly on server.
Make sure you import it correctly and that it is spelled correctly.
const Product = require('./../models/productModel');
Product.find((error, data) => {}); // Product instead of Products

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.
Model.find() no longer accepts callbacks, that's why the error occurs.
It is enough to specify **then** after **find**, and everything will work `Model.find().then((data) => {}))`